# Gradle project import on eclipse -- structural error

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build

I imported a Gradle project into Eclipse using `Gradle > Existing Gradle Project`.

The project `prj-main` has subprojects `subprj-1`, `subprj-2`.

`subprj-2`, requires `subprj-1`.

`subprj-1` doesn’t depend on “anyone” except the external dependencies.

Eclipse Markers is showing me following errors. these aren't the only errors but most peculiar ones:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to configure project subprj-1    build.gradle    /prj-main   line 0  Gradle Error Marker
Failed to configure project subprj-2    build.gradle    /prj-main   line 0  Gradle Error Marker

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    module-info.java /subprj-1/src/main/java    line 1  Java Problem
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    module-info.java /subprj-2/src/main/java    line 1  Java Problem
```

This project is running on IntelliJ in other developers’ environments.
It’s also running in my DOS environment also. However, I’m getting errors to it on Eclipse.

Following are the `build.gradle` full-contents of resply `prj-main`, `subprj-1` and `subprj-2`. i'm also giving the `module-info.java` contents at the bottom.

**prj-main:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'prj-main'
ext.moduleName = 'com.xyz.prj-main'
version = '0.0.1'

def compatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
sourceCompatibility = compatibilityVersion
targetCompatibility = compatibilityVersion
epositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":subprj-1")
    implementation project(":subprj-2")
}

jar {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    manifest {
        attributes('Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName)
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName,
                'Implementation-Title': 'xyz',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Built-Gradle': gradle.gradleVersion
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

        compileJava {
            inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
            doFirst {
                options.compilerArgs = [
                        '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                ]
                classpath = files()
            }
        }
    }
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2.init.Start'
}
```

**subprj-1:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}

apply from: '../versions.gradle'

group = 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-1'
ext.moduleName = 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-1'
version = '0.0.1'

def compatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
sourceCompatibility = compatibilityVersion
targetCompatibility = compatibilityVersion

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // all external dependencies 

    // Apache commons
    implementation ("commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}")
    // ..
}

jar {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    manifest {
        attributes('Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName)
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName,
                'Implementation-Title': 'xyz',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Built-Gradle': gradle.gradleVersion
    }
}

/* to copy all 3rd party jars in dependencies to output dir */
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compileClasspath
    into 'build/libs'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags "localOnly"
    }
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
// Set the location of the JUnit tests.
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test']
        }
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
    }
}
```

**subprj-2:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "net.ossindex.audit" version "0.4.11"
    id 'jacoco'
}

apply from: '../versions.gradle'

group = 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2'
ext.moduleName = 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2'
version = '0.0.1'

def compatibilityVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
sourceCompatibility = compatibilityVersion
targetCompatibility = compatibilityVersion

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   flatDir {
       dirs 'static-libs'
   }
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Internal
    implementation(project(':subprj-1'))

    // all external dependencies from here on 
    implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
    // ..

}

audit {
    user = System.getenv("OSS_AUDIT_USER")
    token = System.getenv("OSS_AUDIT_TOKEN")
    ignore = [ 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2']
    rateLimitAsError = false
}

application {
//    mainModule= 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2'  // i added this line
    mainClassName = 'com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2.init.Start'
}

jar {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    manifest {
        attributes('Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName)
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Automatic-Module-Name': moduleName,
                'Implementation-Title': 'xyz',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                'Built-Date': new Date(),
                'Built-JDK': System.getProperty('java.version'),
                'Built-Gradle': gradle.gradleVersion
    }
}

/* to copy all 3rd party jars in dependencies to output dir */
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compileClasspath
    into 'build/libs'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags "localOnly"
    }
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

// Set the location of the JUnit tests.
sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/test']
        }
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
    }
}
```

Following is `module-info.java` of `subprj-2`. same thing on `module-info.java` of `subprj-1` -- same error to every external dependency.

```
module com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2 {
    requires java.net.http;
    // java.net.http cannor be resolved to a module  -- getting this error to every external dependency
    ...

    requires com.xyz.subprj-1;  // no error to this

    // opens & exports statements are also fine-- no errors to them
    opens com.com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2.subpackage to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    ...

    // Exports
    exports com.com.xyz.prj-main.subprj-2.subpackage to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    ...
}
```

something is wrong in the project structure. i can't see it.

will really appreciate the help.

tried importing difft ways, manipulating the build-path by explicitly defining the module dependencies, putting dependency jars as libraries, among others. also researched on internet.